# Xpage : open attachments - IE freeze

Tags: internet-explorer, xpages, attachment

I have a Notes document that is rendered on an XPage. This document contains file attachments, declared as RichText items in the notes document.
These attachments are displayed using control .

When I click on one of these attachments, IE asks me if I want to open it or download it directly.
If I click on Open, the attachments opens without problem (eg. Word document in MS Word, PDF in Adobe Reader, etc.)

I return to my browser (it doesn’t matter if the attachment is closed or not) and here is where I have the problem:
The browser freezes completely, navigation in the xsp stops working and IE tells me:
*%Server% is not responding due to a long term script* (not sure that is the exact message in English. In French : *%Server% ne répond pas à cause d'un script de longue durée*)

Anyway, I don’t have this problem when using Firefox.

I do not think that the problem comes from the XPage but rather from the configuration of IE or IE himself.

Did someone had this problem before?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I have seen the "long running script" error before. Are you using IE11 and setting compatibility mode to IE10?

Comment: Yes, i'm using IE11. The problems also occurs when changing compatibility mode to IE10.

Comment: Unless it is absolutely necessary to open the attachment in its own window you might want to try and open the attachment within the XPage using a CC like this:

<xp:panel id="embedPDF">
<xp:text escape="false" id="computedField1" contentType="html">
<xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:return "<object width=\"655\" height=\"445\" type=\"application/pdf\" data=\"" + viewScope.get('pdfurl') + "\"></object>";}]]></xp:this.value></xp:text></xp:panel>

I set the viewScope when clicking a view link and it works perfectly and allows all the PDF functions.

Comment: Edit : the problems occurs only when try to open a dialog box using : <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:getComponent('myId').show();}]]>  Where id is the id  of the dialog <xe:dialog id="myId" ...>

Comment: Are you doing a partial or full refresh?  I had similar issues when using a partial refresh, but worked okay with a full refresh.  Others were able to use a partial refresh and we never figured out the cause.  I ended up creating a table within a panel and had the rendered property set to use a scope value that was set when the link/button was clicked and did a partial refresh.  If this works I can make this the answer for you to accept if you so choose.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a partial refresh. When using a full refresh the problem doesn't occurs but i have to use a partial refresh. A solution that i found : go to the theme file and add :

```
<!-- File Download Link -->
   <control>
      <name>Link.FileDownload</name>
      <property>
         <name>styleClass</name>
         <value>xspLinkFileDownload</value>
      </property>
   </control>
<!-- File Download Link --> 
<control> 
        <name>Link.FileDownload</name> 
        <property mode="override"> 
                <name>target</name> 
                <value>_blank</value>
        </property> 
    </control>
```

So when you click on a attachment it will be equivalent to a "rigth click and open in new tab" It solves the problem but i would prefer another one solution